# Value out REDUCE (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

I got a problem with `MAP Reduce`, which I didn't found any solution yet,
In the `REDUCE` method, I can only take the `MAX`, or the `MIN`, when I try to concatenate them in a `TEXT`, I have an error, it does not work
please some one help me tkx !!!

Comment: Please provide the relevant portion of your code and then provide the detail of the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

File (.txt)
[image]
Recuce :
[image]

Error : 
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string